# Discord.py for loop printing the user multiple times?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a command that shows you the top [x] experience players
When I run the command everything is working perfectly except for one thing. It prints some of the users multiple times. Ive checked the code and it seems like whenever people have the same amount of experience as other people, 1 user with that amount of experience is getting printed out multiple times. The rest is getting skipped.

Heres is the py code:

```
@client.command()
async def board(ctx):
    leaderboard = {}
    total = []

    with open('scratch.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)


    for i in users:
        user = str(i)
        exp = int(users[user]["experience"])
        leaderboard[exp] = user
        total.append(exp)

    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)
    index=0
    for amt in total:
        id = leaderboard[amt]
        member = await client.fetch_user(id)
        print(f'{member} total: {amt}')
```

JSON File:

```
{"320927118064222209": {"experience": 6942069420694206942069420, "level": 0}, "414066891246796811": {"experience": 694206942069420, "level": 0}, "261459418665713664": {"experience": 6969, "level": 0}, "401101596638969866": {"experience": 0, "level": 0}, "540680635652767764": {"experience": 15, "level": 0}, "373696339650805760": {"experience": 7, "level": 0}, "399823239037059094": {"experience": 6, "level": 0}, "795218993681006602": {"experience": 6, "level": 0}, "673488589996294145": {"experience": 7, "level": 0}, "754757582421229578": {"experience": 120, "level": 0}, "660774016746913802": {"experience": 96, "level": 0}, "783349784790302742": {"experience": 120, "level": 0}, "252489911611949056": {"experience": 120, "level": 0}, "447055736409686017": {"experience": 120, "level": 0}, "718933950608834602": {"experience": 20, "level": 0}, "739801844141785089": {"experience": 6, "level": 0}, "340317674875781131": {"experience": 26, "level": 0}, "574348578521350146": {"experience": 120, "level": 0}, "625239813116657664": {"experience": 0, "level": 0}, "275369873876713482": {"experience": 1, "level": 0}, "703308818523619358": {"experience": 1500, "level": 0}, "613319859870367754": {"experience": 121, "level": 0}, "701611296906412083": {"experience": 25, "level": 0}, "782219593514090506": {"experience": 0, "level": 0}, "534368639554682890": {"experience": 27, "level": 0}, "724263909003100211": {"experience": 23, "level": 0}}
```

Printing output:

```
clan1500#1500 total: 6942069420694206942069420
mnm#0384 total: 694206942069420
undefined#7426 total: 6969
OIafFromFrozen#1593 total: 1500
HappyKid123#6261 total: 121
clan2300#5041 total: 120
clan2300#5041 total: 120
clan2300#5041 total: 120
clan2300#5041 total: 120
clan2300#5041 total: 120
DemonInvis#0479 total: 96
wawawa#0001 total: 27
Henlo there#3752 total: 26
plant#7541 total: 25
ٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴٴ#0837 total: 23
sak <3#9556 total: 20
AirFloating#6890 total: 15
1_Ninaaa#6779 total: 7
1_Ninaaa#6779 total: 7
MrAaksh#1704 total: 6
MrAaksh#1704 total: 6
MrAaksh#1704 total: 6
menace#0210 total: 1
liz0216#8045 total: 0
liz0216#8045 total: 0
liz0216#8045 total: 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is that the dict leaderboard maps experience to a single user, where there can be many users with the same experience. Yet in list total you store all experiences ( with duplicates)
what I'm guessing you want is to show all users with the same experience. Is that is the case that you should do the following

```
for i in users:
        exp = int(users[user]["experience"])
        if exp not in leaderboard:
            leaderboard[exp]=list()
        leaderboard[exp].append(user)
```

what is happening above is: you store all users in a list mapped to their exp.

then you print it

```
for exp, users_with_same_exp in leaderboard.items():
    for each_users in  users_with_same_exp:
          do your fetch here...
```

once you understand this code look at default dict to make your life a little easier

Comment: Thank you, such a legend you are :)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because JSON uses key value pairs. If you're searching by the experience amount, it will select the **first** id with the corresponding experience amount. I haven't run the code myself, but I also suspect that the code:

```
exp = int(users[user]["experience"])
leaderboard[exp] = user
```

may overwrite the existing experience value with the new user instead of adding a new experience & user entry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still a little bit confused. Do you have a slight idea of what I should change and add in my code? Thanks